# A problem with batch file

Tags: batch-file, uninstallation, subdirectory

I created a batch file, to uninstall my application. My problem is that as result, this uninstallation deleted some files but kept others.

For example one, I created a folder in `C:\\Documents and settings\User-Name\myCompanyName\My Application name\`
This folder contains all files for my application. Now when I uninstall, all these files are deleted. But I want to delete "myCompanyName" folder too from "C:\Documents and settings\User-Name"

The other problem tied with the previous one is that I added a new folder to the start menu called `myComapny` It holds 4 files:

1. exe file
2. config file
3. help file, and
4. uninstall file

When I click on the uninstall file, it removes everything but **still keeps** the folder in the start-menu containing the four files I just listed.

How could I delete the unwanted folders through the **batch file**?

Here is my batch file code:

```
   @echo off
   msiexec /x {DD75996F-C279-420A-9A19-48EF9EFE70C2} 

   RD /s "C:\Program Files\ASGATech"
   RD /s "C:\Documents and Settings\%userprofile%\start menu\programs\ASGATech"
   pause
```

NOTE: I tried to change the extension of the batch file from `bat` to `cmd`
I also tried to get the current login user %userprofile% to go to his/her start menu. If this way is wrong, please inform me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the C:\Documents and Settings - this is already in the %userprofile% tag.

`RD /s "%userprofile%\start menu\programs\ASGATech"`

Comment: what about the first line RD /s "C:\Program Files\ASGATech"
it's also doesn't removed

Comment: Might it be some problem with that 'rd' checks with the user "are you sure (y/n)"? Do you get query? Try adding /Q after /S. This means that it will not ask the users permission. I tested these and it did delete folders like you specified.

Comment: mmmmmmmm how bad luck it's still not working with me ... what do you think the problem is ?!?! 
i put the batch file in the User program's menun under a folder called ASGATech. this folder holds the application primary output, help shortcut config, and uninstall shortcut...
so what is the problem

Comment: hard to say without more input. try to take @echo off away and see if you get some constructive output